# Highcharts - Highstocks. Show all x-axis labels

Tags: highcharts

I have highstocks set up to display two series of data.

When I zoom all the way the x-axis label for one of the series is always missing.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/0b56nbkc/)

```
    $(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });
        var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                "renderTo": "container"
            },
            plotOptions: {
                "column": {
                    "stacking": "normal"
                }
            },
            series: [{
                "type": "column",
                "name": "column 1",
                "color": "#1d8ecd",
                "data": [
                    [1296511200000, 974],
                    [1301605200000, 1618],
                    [1306875600000, 990],
                    [1312146000000, 1720],
                    [1317416400000, 516],
                    [1322690400000, 1472],
                    [1328047200000, 349],
                    [1333227600000, 1781],
                    [1338498000000, 649],
                    [1343768400000, 1124],
                    [1349038800000, 829],
                    [1354312800000, 1615],
                    [1359669600000, 1181]

                ]

            }, {
                "type": "column",
                "name": "column 2",
                "color": "#636466",
                "data": [
                    [1293832800000, 1913],
                    [1298930400000, 1269],
                    [1304197200000, 567],
                    [1309467600000, 668],
                    [1314824400000, 722],
                    [1320098400000, 442],
                    [1325368800000, 1558],
                    [1330552800000, 1831],
                    [1335819600000, 373],
                    [1341090000000, 275],
                    [1346446800000, 1540],
                    [1351720800000, 998]
                ]
            }],

        });
    });
```

Any ideas why is this happening and if I can force it to display all x-axis labels, at least when there is space for it?

Comment: Please don't try to circumnavigate the SO rules and only provide a fiddle link, you need to include code in the question itself

Comment: Do you mean that each tick should be on each column ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan. Yes i'd expect that at full zoom , all columns should have a date label on x-axis. At the moment only gray columns have this, but none of the blue ones

Comment: You can use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner) / [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositions) to define ticks.

Comment: i think i got it solved. When we have multiple series, empty values on the x-axis should be filled with null and not omitted.